# How to create an BQ external table on top of the delta table in GCS and show only latest snapshot

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, delta-lake

I am trying to create an external BQ external table on top of delta table which uses google storage as a storage layer. On the delta table, we perform DML which includes deletes.

I can create an BQ external table on top of the gs bucket where all the delta files exists. However, it is pulling even the delete records since BQ external table cannot read the transaction logs of delta where it says which parquet files to consider and which one to remove.

is there a way we can expose the latest snapshot of the delta table (gs location) in BQ as an external table apart from doing it programmatically copying data from delta to BQ?

Comment: Do you have a naming convention with your file? What is the frequency of your file update?

Answer (score 4):

So this question is asked like more than a year ago but I have tricky but powerful addition to Oliver's answer which eliminates data duplication and additional load logic.

**Step 1** As Oliver suggested generate symlink_format_manifest files; you can either trigger it everytime you've updated or you can add a tblproperty to your file as stated [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/presto-integration.html#step-3-update-manifests) to
automatically create those files when delta table is updated;

```
ALTER TABLE delta.`<path-to-delta-table>` SET TBLPROPERTIES(delta.compatibility.symlinkFormatManifest.enabled=true)
```

**Step 2** Create a external table that points to delta table location

```
> bq mkdef --source_format=PARQUET "gs://test-delta/*.parquet" > bq_external_delta_logs
> bq mk --external_table_definition=bq_external_delta_logs test.external_delta_logs
```

**Step 3** Create another external table pointing to symlink_format_manifest/manifest file

```
> bq mkdef --autodetect --source_format=CSV gs://test-delta/_symlink_format_manifest/manifest > bq_external_delta_manifest
> bq mk --table --external_table_definition=bq_external_delta_manifest test.external_delta_manifest
```

**Step 4** Create a view with following query

```
> bq mk \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--view \
'SELECT
  *
FROM
  `project_id.test.external_delta_logs` 
WHERE
  _FILE_NAME in (select * from `project_id.test.external_delta_logs`)' \
test.external_delta_snapshot
```

Now you can get the latest snapshot whenever your delta table refreshed  from *test.external_delta_snapshot* view without any additional loading or data duplication. **A downside of this solution** is, in case of schema changes you have to add new fields to you table definition either manually or from your spark pipeline using BQ client etc. For those who are curious about how this solution works, please continue reading.

---

How this works;

symlink manifest files contains list of parquet files in new line delimited format pointing to current delta version partitions;

```
gs://delta-test/......-part1.parquet
gs://delta-test/......-part2.parquet
....
```

In addition to our delta location, we are defining another external table by treating this manifest file as CSV file (its actually a single column CSV file). The view we've defined takes advantage of _FILE_NAME pseudo column mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#the_file_name_pseudo_column), which points to parquet file location of every row in table. As stated in docs, _FILE_NAME pseudo column is defined for every external table that points to data stored in **Cloud Storage** and **Google Drive**.

So at this point, we have the list of parquet files required for loading latest snapshot and ability to filter files we want to read using _FILE_NAME column. The view we have defined just defines this procedure to get the latest snapshot. Whenever our delta table gets updated, manifest and delta log table will look for the newest data therefore we will always get the latest snapshot without any additional loading or data duplication.

Last word, its a known fact that execution on external tables are more expensive(execution cost) than BQ managed tables, so its better to experiment with dual writes as Oliver suggested and external table solution like you asked. Storage is cheaper than execution so there may be some cases where keeping data in both GCS and BQ costs less than keeping an external table like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also developing this kind of pipeline where we dump our delta lake files in GCS and present it on Bigquery. The generation of manifest file from your GCS delta files will give you the latest snapshot based on what version current set on your delta files. Then you need to create a custom script to parse that manifest file to get the list of files and then run a bq load mentioning those files.

```
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(<path-to-delta-table>)
deltaTable.generate("symlink_format_manifest")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below workaround might work for small datasets.

Have a separate BQ table.
Read the delta lake files into a DataFrame and then df.overwrite into the BigQuery table.